# Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. when I call scanf

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, scanf

my program is getting out of bounds whenever I call scanf.
I can't figure why.
Please help.

thanks.

```
.L2:
leal    -4(%esp)        ,%esp
leal    -4(%ebp)        ,%eax
pushl   %eax
pushl   readChar                #"%c"
call    scanf               #call scanf for the char

(gdb) info registers
 eax            0xffffced0  -12592 #the correct address of the place we want to insert the parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake. The problem is with this statement

```
pushl   readChar
```

This pushes the long value found at readChar, not the address of readChar. What you need is this:

```
pushl   $readChar
```

Note the dollar sign ('$').